# Does gluing polyhedra together give you a CW complex?

Tags: cw-complexes

If I take a finite collection of polyhedra and glue their faces together (potentially gluing two faces of the same polyhedron together) to get a closed 3-manifold, is this always a CW-complex? Can I use the Euler characteristic on the number of vertices, edges, faces and polyhedra?

Comment: If I ensure that I get a manifold, can I use the Euler characteris #vertices -#edges +#faces - #polyhedra

Comment: Gluing pairs of faces of polyhedra to each other, and potentially gluing faces of polyhedra tofaces of the same polyhedron.